# Can I set up my server to automatically pull updates from a branch when new commits come in?

Tags: git, deployment, github, git-workflow

Say I have a project in a git repository. The project has a branch called "Stable" or "Production" where the current version of the project is always stable. I have a production server that ideally should always have the most recent version of the stable branch. I know I could have a cron job run a pull at a specific interval, but I'm not really happy with that solution. Often I could push as much as 5 hotfixes in an hour after discovering a bug in the stable branch. I would like the production server to instantly pull those new commits once they have been pushed.

**What would be the simplest way of doing this?** My fallback solution will be to have my production server run a pull every minute or so, so anything short of that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do post-commit hook which will push to the production server.

Also, the pulling every minute doesn't look as a bad solution.

Comment: +1 for the post-commit hook.  Polling is less ideal, though I guess the OP did specify "simplest"...  :-/

Comment: I'm a tad confused by the first sentence of your answer. My question has nothing to do with the pushing, just the production server's pulling :S

Comment: @Codemonkey You could have a hook in local repo which will push changes to the remote. If you need to catch a moment then the remote repo receives changes, you could use "post-update" hook. Please refer to the http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html it has good explanation and all possible hooks you may consider.

Comment: I'll mark it as correct for the polling comment, but I'm still not following the post-commit hook. Pushing the changes to the remote, again, is not my issue. Unless you consider the production server to be the remote, which I don't.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a build server(Bamboo, Hudson, Cruisecontrol, etc...), you can also setup tasks to trigger a pull in another branch when updates are detected in the source. We have tasks setup in Bamboo which do such using native git.

Comment: Afaik, the build servers detect updates by periodical pulling, so it's practically the same. However the approach has more features.

Comment: AnthillPro at least has hooks for post-commit triggers rather than polling. Some other tools may as well. Internally, we use this so that when the website has a commit, a new "build" is created and automatically pushed to a test server (about a minute total). We can then promote that to production on demand .